# Trouble with getting list of all channel members with Telethon API

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I use TELETNON API for Python to get a list of all channel members. The documentation says that there is a limit for 200 participants at a time, but it can be removed by setting the Aggressive = true parameter. There are 207 participants in my channel, without a parameter, it gives me 200 participants, as it should. But with the parameter, only 187 participants are given to me, instead of the prescribed 207. What could be the matter?

[Method used: client.get_participants(chat)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD7xj.png)

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?highlight=iter_participants#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_participants

Comment: `aggressive` is a hack. It is not guaranteed to improve the results.

Comment: Maybe the rest are bots?